# How to show covariance is 0 for this AR(2) process

Tags: time-series, econometrics, covariance, arma

Can someone please help me show that $Cov(X_t,X_{(t-1)}=0$ for the following AR(2) process with no restrictions on the first lag.

$x_{t} = c + φx_{(t-2)} + e_{t}$

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You may want to assume your process is stationary (you'll understand later why). The characteristic polynomial of your process being $P (B) = 1 - \varphi B^2$, with $B$ the backshift operator, you can see easily your process will be stationary when $|\varphi| < 1$.

Once your process is stationary, you know in particular that $\mbox{cov}(X_t, X_{s})$ is a function of $|t-s|$. Now, let's remark that 
$$X_t = c + \varphi X_{t-2} + e_t \quad \mbox{ and }\quad X_{t+1} = c + \varphi X_{t-1} + e_{t+1}.$$
The noise $(e_t)$ being $iid$ with zero mean, it follows that
$$\mbox{cov}(X_t, X_{t+1}) = \varphi^2 \mbox{cov}(X_{t-2}, X_{t-1})$$
but $\mbox{cov}(X_t, X_{t+1}) = \mbox{cov}(X_{t-2}, X_{t-1})$, then
$$(1 - \varphi^2) \mbox{cov}(X_t, X_{t+1}) = 0,$$
which proves that $\mbox{cov}(X_t, X_{t+1}) = 0$.

Comment: I edited this but did not change the proof part of your answer.  However I think the next to last equation should be $(1-1/\varphi^2) cov(X_t, X_t$$_+$$_1)=0$ .

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i note the above proves cov(Xt,Xt+1)=0, however i need to show cov(Xt,Xt-1)=0.

Comment: @Jack If you set $s=t+1$ then $\text{Cov}(X_{t},X_{t+1})=\text{Cov}(X_{s-1},X_{s})=\text{Cov}(X_{s},X_{s-1})$ i.e. you already have your proof.